# Getting error in hook: Symbol’s function definition is void: \(setf\ ekg-note-tags\)

Tags: hooks, error, setf

I'm writing a pre-save hook for ekg (emacs knowledge graph), and getting an error I don't know how to figure out.

The error is `triples--with-transaction: Symbol’s function definition is void: \(setf\ ekg-note-tags\)`

and my hook definition is like this:

```
(defun get-ekg-body-tags (note)
  "Get #tags from body of EKG note"
  (let* ((string (ekg-note-text note))
         (regexp "#\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)")
         matches
         (newtags (save-match-data
                    (let ((pos 0)
                          matches)
                      (while (string-match regexp string pos)
                        (push (match-string 1 string) matches)
                        (setq pos (match-end 0)))
                      matches))))
    (seq-uniq (append newtags (ekg-note-tags note)))))

(defun my-ekg-note-pre-save-hook (note)
  "Apply #tags found in body to the note's tags"
  (let ((tags (get-ekg-body-tags note)))
    (message "Setting tags to %s" tags)
    (setf (ekg-note-tags note)
          (mapcar (lambda (tag)
                    (string-trim (downcase (string-replace "," "" tag)))) tags))
    ))

(add-hook 'ekg-note-pre-save-hook 'my-ekg-note-pre-save-hook)
```

It looks like it's somehow trying to call `(setf ekg-note-tags)` which makes me think my pre-save hook is *returning* the setf call rather than calling it. The stack trace when the error occurs is this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function \(setf\ ekg-note-tags\))
  signal(void-function (\(setf\ ekg-note-tags\)))
  triples--with-transaction(#<sqlite db=0x114008e30 name=/Users/garyo/.config/emacs/triples.db> #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_59>)
  ekg--save-note-in-buffer()
  ekg-edit-finalize()
  funcall-interactively(ekg-edit-finalize)
  command-execute(ekg-edit-finalize)
```

so it is well after my hook has run. If I edebug the hook, then everything works as expected, no error.
Any ideas? Maybe the `setf` macro isn't getting properly expanded?

Comment: Actually the error looks like it's trying to call a function named `(setf ekg-note-tags)` with the space and paren. I can't figure out why it thinks it should do that.

Comment: I think something's going wrong with the setf macro expansion. In the debugger, my pre-save-hook looks like this: `(let ((tags (get-ekg-body-tags note)) (old-tags (ekg-note-tags note))) (message "Setting tags to %s, old tags %s" tags old-tags) (let* ((v note)) (\(setf\ ekg-note-tags\) tags v)) (ekg--normalize-note note))` which contains that weird function name. What could be going wrong here? (This is with a somewhat modified version of the function above, but still containing the same setf)

Comment: I see that this idea, functions named "(setf NAME)", comes from Common Lisp, so maybe since ekg is using cl-lib, there is some confusion about which `setf` is being used?? See the end of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Adding-Generalized-Variables.html